# ArcGIS Pro 3.2 fill gaps line section using another line layer

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, line, merge, road

I extracted two lines layers of road condition. One was surveyed when the roads were dry. The other layer is when the roads were wet. The dry layer has some gaps
And I want to fill these gaps with the sections of the wet layer. So I can have one road layer without any gaps. Is it a tool that I can use? I thought about the merge tool. I am afraid, it is going to change the entire dry layer. I just want to replace the gap by the wet section.

Comment: How big are the gaps?  If they are within tolerances you could try a snap or Integrate.  (Use the latter on a copy or edit session to see if you like it; it changes the layer.  But if the gaps are larger you might try several things.  You could intersect your lines (if they match) then select lines without any dry attributes and add them to your dry layer.   I supose  you could buffer your dry layer a small amount flat ended, use the buffer to erase the wet, then add the leftover wet to the dry and run the snap or Integrate.